# MySQL sql dump wrong char encoding

Tags: mysql, wordpress, character-encoding

We did a wordpress sql backup into sql dump, I can see that the CHARSET is set to utf8 but for some reason all the non english text shows up like this:

╫ó╫¿╫¢╫ץ╫¬ ╫ó╫ש╫ª╫ץ╫ס

Is this something we can fix? which encoding is it?

Comment: nothing to do with the dump and everything to do  with whatever environment you're viewing the dump in... e.g. if you're dumping your utf8 dump to a terminal, then that terminal has to be set to utf8 as well. the terminal has NO idea what sql is, nor should it ever - it's just displaying some text. so `set names='utf8'` in the sql is just some random garbage, not a directive to the terminal.

Comment: This is the what the wordpress dump, it was already set to utf8 but the characters are wrong, can we reverse the process

Comment: not really. once text has been mangled through character sets, you can't 100% reliably go the other way.

Comment: Can we figure out what sql dump use to encode the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the proper encoding, for some reason it encoded all the Hebrew chars in CP862